# Drawing rectilinear curves in Tikz, aka an Etch-a-Sketch drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to draw a rectilinear path by starting at a particular location, and then prescribing increments in the horizontal and vertical directions.

I am currently doing something like this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick] (20,12) -- (18,12);
    \draw [ultra thick] (18,12) -- (18,10);
    \draw [ultra thick] (18,10) -- (16,10);
    \draw [ultra thick] (16,10) -- (16,8);
    \draw [ultra thick] (16,8) -- (12,8);
    \draw [ultra thick] (12,8) -- (12,10);
    \draw [ultra thick] (12,10) -- (8,10);
    \draw [ultra thick] (8,10) -- (8,12);
    \draw [ultra thick] (8,12) -- (6,12);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,12) -- (6,14);
    \draw [ultra thick] (6,14) -- (4,14);
    % etc ...

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this requires that I locate each point, when what is much easier (for my particular case) is to just indicate the horizontal or vertical distance from one point to the next.

I have tried something like this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (A) at (20,12) {};
   \node (B) at (18,12) {};
   \node (C) at (18,10) {};
   \node (D) at (16,10) {};

   \draw (A) |- ++ (-2,0)  -| (B);
   \draw (B) |- ++ (0, -2) -| (C);
   \draw (C) |- ++ (-2, 0) -| (D);
   % etc
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like the `++ (-2,0)` bit seems to be on the right track, but naming the nodes is tedious, and this doesn't produce what I have in mind.

Is there some way to do what I have in mind with simple notation?  Something like

```
Start at (20,12)
Go left 2 units
Go down 2 units
Go left 2 units
% etc
```

Aka, Etch-a-Sketch style?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\draw (20,12) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3,0) -- ++(45:3);`

Use `++` before each new incremental coordinate to make it relative to the last one and put the pencil there.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw (20,12) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3,0) -- ++(30:3) {[rounded corners=10pt]-- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,-6)} -- ++(-7,0) -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, combining this with the -| or |- path operators can simplify the code even further; the following two pieces of code produce the same result:

```
\tikz\draw (20,12) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(2,0);\par\bigskip
```

and

```
\tikz\draw (20,12) -| ++(2,2) -| ++(3,1) -- ++(1,0) |- ++(2,-3);
```

I don't think that defining commands in this case adds anything; in fact, I think it reduces the functionality of the existing syntax (which is already simple). The example demonstrates that you can use, for example, polar coordinates and modify (up to TikZ limitations) the path attributes midways; even if the current question doesn't require this, it's a good thing to have the possibility to do those kind of modification if they are required.

Comment: Thanks - this is in fact exactly what I wanted.   And it doesn't have the problem that segments aren't meeting up exactly at the corners.   Perfect!

Comment: @Donna You're welcome. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  So it looks like there are a couple of new features here, at least one of which I was wondering about.   It looks like you can change the line style midstream, which is very handy, and exactly something I wanted to do.  I want to fill the resulting rectilinear polygons, so always need closed polygons, but only want portions of the border to be, say, ultra thick.  So I'll try your trick above for getting rounded corners midway.   But what does the `(30:3)` notation do?  And `cycle`?

Comment: Trying this out, I see that the `(30:3)` indicates an angle (30 degrees), and `cycle` means "return to the beginning" (or so it seems).  Turns out, though, it is not possible to change the line style midway.  Oh well.

Comment: @Donna Yes, `(<angle>:<distance>)` has the meaning you guesses, and yes, line width (as well as color and other attributes) cannot be changed midway for a single path due to TikZ limitations.

Answer (score 18):

Not sure it is what is required, but here is a `rectilinear` decoration which sort of achieves the required effect:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{rectilinear}{start}{%
\state{start}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/2,
  next state=draw above]{%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}{\pgfpointorigin}%
}
\state{draw above}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/2, 
  next state=draw below]{%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \pgftransformreset%
  \pgfpointanchor{@1}{center}\pgfgetlastxy\a\b%
  \pgfpointanchor{@2}{center}\pgfgetlastxy\c\d%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\a}{\d}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\c}{\d}}%
  \pgfnodealias{@1}{@2}%
}
\state{draw below}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/2, 
  next state=draw above]{%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \pgftransformreset%
  \pgfpointanchor{@1}{center}\pgfgetlastxy\a\b%
  \pgfpointanchor{@2}{center}\pgfgetlastxy\c\d%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\c}{\b}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\c}{\d}}%
  \pgfnodealias{@1}{@2}%
}
\state{final}{%
  \pgftransformreset%
  \pgfpointanchor{@1}{center}\pgfgetlastxy\a\b%
  \pgfpointdecoratedpathlast\pgfgetlastxy\c\d%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\a}{\d}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\c}{\d}}%
}
}
\tikzset{rectilinear/.style={
  decoration={rectilinear, #1}, decorate
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, line join=round, line cap=round]
\draw [gray, postaction={rectilinear, draw=red}]
  (0,4) -- ++(30:2) -- ++(300:3);
\draw [gray, postaction={rectilinear, draw=green!50!black}]
  (0,2) circle [radius=1];
\draw  [gray, postaction={rectilinear={segment length=0.25cm}, draw=blue}]
  (0,0) -- (3,1) arc (90:-90:1) .. controls ++(180:1) and ++(225:1) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here four  macro `\Start`, `\Goleft`, `\Godown` and `\Goup` to creat the desired path.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt}}

\newcommand{\Start}[1]{\node (A) at #1 {};}
\newcommand{\Goleft}[1]{\draw($(A)+( -0.5\pgflinewidth ,0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--+(#1,0)node(A){};}
\newcommand{\Godown}[1]{\draw($(A)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$)--+(0,-#1)node(A){};}
\newcommand{\Goup}[1]{\draw($(A)+(-0.5\pgflinewidth,0)$)--+(0,#1)node(A){};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \Start{(20,12)}
   \Goleft{2}
   \Godown{2}
   \Goleft{3}
   \Godown{1}
   \Goleft{4}
   \Goup{3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that helps alot.   i'd like to also adjust the line width, which did by adding `[line width=8pt] for example.    The problem, though is that the lines don't match up, and so the line edges are visible at the corners.   it seems like I need to add something  like  a small filled square at each corner.

Comment: Just add `line width=1pt` (or what satisfy you) in the front of `tikzpicture` environment like this 
`\begin{tikzpikture}[line width=1pt]`

Comment: Yes, I did that.  But it still seemed to suffer from this problem that the corner segments don't match up.  The solution from @GonzaloMedina doesn't have this problem.

Comment: My bad.  I fixed a bug, and this solution works just as the one below.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice implementation. Funny that you chose to call `Goleft` the macro which actually go... right! ^^